# Spring autowire only if bean is present as method argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using `@ConditionalOnProperty` to create a `FileCompressor` bean:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "file.rollover.sink", name = "compress", matchIfMissing = true)
public FileCompressor fileCompressor() {
    return new DefaultFileCompressor(...);
}
```

I would like to autowire `FileCompressor` bean only if it is present, `null` if `file.rollover.sink.compress=false` as a method argument.
But if I try to define it like:

```
@Bean
public RolloverTask rolloverTask(final IntervalCalculator intervalCalculator, final @Autowired(required = false) FileCompressor fileCompressor) {
    return new RolloverTask(intervalCalculator, fileCompressor);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Parameter 1 of method rolloverTask in com.example.FileRolloverSinkConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.example.compressor.FileCompressor' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'fileCompressor' in 'FileRolloverSinkConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (file.rollover.sink.compress) found different value in property 'compress'
```

What changes should I make to autowire or pass `null` if not present?

-- EDIT --

My solution:

```
private FileCompressor fileCompressor;

@Autowired(required = false)
public void setFileCompressor(final FileCompressor fileCompressor) {
    this.fileCompressor = fileCompressor;
}


@Bean
public RolloverTask rolloverTask(final IntervalCalculator intervalCalculator) {
        log.info("Creating a new rollover task with{} a file compressor", fileCompressor == null ? "out" : "");
        return new RolloverTask(intervalCalculator, fileCompressor);
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "file.rollover.sink", name = "compress", matchIfMissing = true)
public FileCompressor fileCompressor() {
    return new DefaultFileCompressor(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make a sense to have `matchIfMissing = true` without `havingValue =`. Because if you don't have a property bean will created and if you will have a property with any value bean will created.

You can solve it in this way:

```
    @Autowired(required = false)
    private FileCompressor fileCompressor;

    @Bean
    public RolloverTask rolloverTaskWithCompressor(final IntervalCalculator intervalCalculator, final FileCompressor fileCompressor) {
        return new RolloverTask(intervalCalculator, fileCompressor);
   }
```

or have different bean definitions for both versions of `RolloverTask`:

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "file.rollover.sink", name = "compress", havingValue = "no", matchIfMissing = false)
    public RolloverTask rolloverTask(IntervalCalculator intervalCalculator) {
        return new RolloverTask(intervalCalculator, null);
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "file.rollover.sink", name = "compress", havingValue = "yes", matchIfMissing = true)
    public RolloverTask rolloverTaskWithCompressor(final IntervalCalculator intervalCalculator, final FileCompressor fileCompressor) {
        return new RolloverTask(intervalCalculator, fileCompressor);
   }
```

Comment: I went with a similar solution to your first proposal, I don't like having 2 definitions, 1 when property is true, and one when false. My bean definition is a bit more complex than this example... I've put my solution in an edit.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the annotations `@ConditionalOnBean` and `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`

I didn't try the code but it should be like this :

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(FileCompressor.class)
public RolloverTask rolloverTask(final IntervalCalculator intervalCalculator, final FileCompressor fileCompressor) {
    return new RolloverTask(intervalCalculator, fileCompressor);
}
```

and

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(FileCompressor.class)
public RolloverTask rolloverTask(final IntervalCalculator intervalCalculator) {
    return new RolloverTask(intervalCalculator, null);
}
```